# Generate Multiple random multidimensional normal distribution in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I want to generate multiple(1000) random multidimensional(10000) normal distributions with different densities in matlab.

I know how to generate a multivariate normal distribution using mvnrnd() function but I was wondering if I could do it in a automated way.  Maybe have the mean and sigma generated by rand function then feed it into the mvnrnd() function somehow?

Also would it be possible to generate some(300) of these in a hyper spherical formation where the means are distributed spherically in the multidimensional space. They should have the same density and spread/sigma.

Thank you for your input in advance.

Comment: Not sure where the problem is, put everything into a loop?

Comment: Yes. I am trying to achieve that but running into multiple problems. First of all I have no idea how to randomly generate a symmetric positive semi definite matrix.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/357980/matlab-code-for-generating-random-symmetric-positive-definite-matrix

Comment: Forgive me but I tried to run the sited code but giving me a error message 'Error: Function definitions are not permitted in this context.' on the first line.  I am new to programming in matlab bear with me.

Comment: You can't copy-paste a function into the Command Window. Please read the [documentation about functions](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/function-basics.html) (or type `doc function`). StackOverflow, is not a substitute for reading the documentation, doing your own Google research, or spending time with tutorials to learn the basics of the language.